# Stop SUM rounding SQL

Tags: sql-server, lightswitch-2013

I am creating a SQL view using this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(MONTH(DtRepairComplete), 0) AS RepairMonthNo
,ISNULL(FORMAT(DtRepairComplete, 'MMMM'), GETDATE()) AS RepairMonth
,ISNULL(YEAR(DtRepairComplete), 0) AS RepairYear
,ISNULL(SUM(IntRepairCosts), 0) AS TotalRepairCosts
,COUNT(IntIncidentID) AS RepairCount

FROM Incident d

GROUP BY FORMAT(DtRepairComplete, 'MMMM'),


YEAR(DtRepairComplete)
,MONTH(DtRepairComplete)
,FORMAT(DtRepairComplete, 'MMMM')
```

IntRepairCosts is data type decimal(18,0) on the table. When I attach the view to my project, it is rounding to whole numbers. As this value represents a cost, I need it to be accurate and not round up or down.

Can I stop this field from rounding and still SUM per the query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `IntReportCosts` is `decimal(18,0)`, then it doesn't have any costs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure what you mean. By 'cost' I mean a dollar amount.

Comment: . . That is "it doesn't have any cents".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data type of Decimal(18,0) will have no digits after the decimal and will round up to the nearest whole value. This is why you are experiencing this. You can test this as follows:

```
Declare @Value decimal(18,0) = 123.678
Select @Value
```

You will get 124

Off hand I don't know why someone would create a type of Decimal(N,0) instead of just an int or bigint. And when you're working with money, a Decimal(N,0) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: When the value is stored in the database, any values after the decimal place are lost because you've told SQL Server you don't care about them. So I don't see how you would be able to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the column to be decimal(18,2) and it appears to work now. Thanks again.